# How to bypass multiple parameter from url to controller

Tags: php, laravel, mysqli, laravel-5.8

I have 2 parameters that I put in my url. What I want is how to get these 2 parameters, so it can be read from my controller.

I've try this so the controller can read the parameter:

```
$id = Input::get('id');
```

but when I check with dd, the parameter is null

Here is my code:

The link a href on view:

```
{{ URL('/lap_spd/tambahspd/'.$items->nosurat.'/'.$items->id )}}
```

web php :

```
Route::get('lap_spd/tambahspd/{id}/{nosurat}', function($id, $nosurat){
return redirect()->action(
    'lapspdController@tambahuwong', ['id' => $id], ['nosurat' => $nosurat]);
});
```

lapspdController php:

```
public function tambahuwong($id, $nosurat) { 
 $id = Input::get('id');
 $nosurat = Input::get('nosurat');

$data3 = DB::table('list_nama')
          ->where('id_nosurat', 'nosurat')
          ->toSql();
          dd($data3);
```

so the output that I want - is the parameter can pass to variable on controller.

Thanks for respone before and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: They are in your signature `public function tambahuwong($id, $nosurat)` why don't you just use them?

Comment: as far as i try, the $id and $nosurat are giving null value, and i not quite understand why it's null. that's why i use $id = Input::get('id'); to get the value. but no work :/

Comment: Why do you need to redirect? Does `Route::get('lap_spd/tambahspd/{id}/{nosurat}', 'lapspdController@tambahuwong')` instead of redirecting not work for you?

Comment: here's the result sir when use dd 

select * from `list_nama` where `id_nosurat` = ?  << still got null value

Comment: `where('id_nosurat', 'nosurat')` should be `where('id_nosurat', $nosurat)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the parameters in a single array in your web.php file

```
return redirect()->action(
    'lapspdController@tambahuwong', ['id' => $id, 'nosurat' => $nosurat]);
```

In lapspdController php:

```
public function tambahuwong($id, $nosurat) { 
//remove these lines and use the variables from the parameters directly
 //$id = Input::get('id');
 //$nosurat = Input::get('nosurat');

$data3 = DB::table('list_nama')
          ->where('id_nosurat',$nosurat)
          ->toSql();
          dd($data3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in view:
<a href="{{route('check',['nosurat'=>$items->nosurat,'id'=>$items->id])}}"></a>

in route:

 Route::get('lap_spd/tambahspd/{id}/{nosurat}','HomeController@tambahuwong')
  ->name('check');

in controller:
public function tambahuwong($id,$nosurat) {
$check_id=$id;
$nosurat_name=$nosurat;
dd($check_id);
dd($nosurat_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change

```
return redirect()->action(
    'lapspdController@tambahuwong', ['id' => $id], ['nosurat' => $nosurat]);
});
```

to

```
return redirect()->action(
    'lapspdController@tambahuwong', ['id' => $id, 'nosurat' => $nosurat]);
});
```

?